# Depthwise convolution training loss is not decreasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

the model is for binary classification.
this is my model:

```
im_input= layers.Input(shape=[160,160,3])
x = layers.Conv2D(30,(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same')(im_input)
z = layers.DepthwiseConv2D((3,3),strides=2,padding='same',depth_multiplier=10)(im_input)
x = layers.ReLU()(x)
z = layers.ReLU()(z)
x = layers.Conv2D(60,(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same')(x)
z = layers.Conv2D(60,(3,3),strides=2,padding='same')(z)
x = layers.ReLU()(x)
z = layers.ReLU()(z)
x = layers.Concatenate()([x,z])
x = layers.Conv2D(120,(3,3),strides=2,padding='same')(x)
x = layers.ReLU()(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(200,(3,3),strides=2,padding='same')(x)
x = layers.ReLU()(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(400,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same')(x)
x = layers.ReLU()(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(900,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
#x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(100,activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(x)
out = layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)
smodel = tf.keras.Model(inputs=im_input, outputs=out, name="myModel2")
smodel.summary()
```

and this is the loss function:

```
cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
```

the optimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.001)
```

any suggestions for the optimizer?

why does this model loss is not decreasing? is there something wrong in model? someone, please help...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SGD, you should try Adam optimizer.

Also, in your network, increase the units in the Dense layer as this is the final representation of the data.

Finally, the number of filters should be less, keep it maximum to 512.

If your input size is small, then reduce the number of layers also.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the optimizer to Adam
I don't think there is anything wrong with the code.
Also try changing the dense layers-
after flatten use dense layer with 512 units and then directly your final output layer.
You don't need so many dense layers.
Also can you post your loss value, if its two large then maybe there is something wrong with your Train labels.